# Why does including "boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp" ruins socket?

Tags: c++, boost, winsock2

I have a working code of the server application. 
Now I need to use cpp_int in my project.
However, when I just try to include **boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp**

> accept(listeningSocket, (sockaddr*)&client, &sizeofclient);

returns **INVALID_SOCKET**, and programm terminates with the code 3.

This is a code of server.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Ws2tcpip.h>
//#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp> // reason of the probmlem
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
constexpr auto MSIZE = 4096;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    WSADATA wsData;
    WORD ver = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    if (WSAStartup(ver, &wsData) != 0)
    {
        cerr << "Can't initialise winsock\nQuiting...\n";
        return 1;
    }   
    SOCKET listeningSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (listeningSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        cerr << "Can't create a socket!\nQuiting...\n";
        return 2;
    }
    sockaddr_in hint;
    hint.sin_family = AF_INET;
    hint.sin_port = htons(54000);
    hint.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    bind(listeningSocket, (sockaddr*)&hint, sizeof(hint));
    listen(listeningSocket, SOMAXCONN);
    cout << "Listenning\n";
    sockaddr_in client;
    int sizeofclient = sizeof(client);
    SOCKET clientSocket = accept(listeningSocket, (sockaddr*)&client, &sizeofclient);
    if (clientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        cerr << "Invalid socket.\nQuiting...\n";
        return 3;
    }

    char host[NI_MAXHOST];
    char service[NI_MAXHOST];
    ZeroMemory(host, NI_MAXHOST);
    ZeroMemory(service, NI_MAXHOST);
    char buf[MSIZE];
    while (1)
    {
        ZeroMemory(buf, MSIZE);
        int bytesReceived = recv(clientSocket, buf, MSIZE, 0);
        if (bytesReceived == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            cerr << "Error in recv()\n";
            break;
        }
        if (bytesReceived == 0)
        {
            cout << "Client disconnected" << endl;
            break;
        }
        if (strcmp("\r\n", buf) != 0)
        {
            cout << "(Request from " << host << ") >>  " << buf << endl;
            if (strcmp(buf, "hello") == 0)
            {
                char response[100] = "Greetings!\n\r";
                send(clientSocket, response, sizeof(response) + 1, 0);
            }
            else 
            {
                char response[100] = "Invalid command!\n\r";
                send(clientSocket, response, sizeof(response) + 1, 0);
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "Quiting program\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you should print the value of `errno` when an error occurred or use `perror` or `strerror`.

Comment: Does changing `bind` to `::bind` help?

Comment: @Bodo Tried. `perror` doesn't show any error

Comment: Or getting rid of that `using namespace std;` and explicitly adding `std::` when needed?

Comment: Yes! Thank you! `::bind` works

Comment: `accept` and `socket` are defined in winsock2.h.  How is that getting included?

Comment: You also need to `#include <cstring>` (and possibly other headers), realize that `recv()` doesn't 0-terminate what it reads, account for it returning not as many bytes as requested, and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is a side effect of your use of `using namespace std;`.

When you include `<boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>`, it pulls in [`std::bind()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) from C++'s `<functional>` header, and that is the function your code ends up calling instead of Winsock's `bind()` function. Thus, `listen()` and `accept()` fail because the server socket is not bound to a network interface (and your code is not checking for errors on `bind()` and `listen()`). Had you checked the error codes for `listen()` and `accept()`, you would have seen that they were both reporting `WSAEINVAL` (meaning "The socket has not been bound with bind" and "The listen function was not invoked prior to accept", respectively).

You need to either

- [Get rid of `using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/), and then explicitly use the `std::` prefix where needed (this is the preferred solution!)
- when calling `bind()`, you can prefix it with `::` to tell the compiler that you want to call the `bind()` function from the global namespace (Win32 APIs, like Winsock, do not use namespaces in C++) rather than the one from the `std` namespace.